`kexec -e` can work, but `kexec -p` didn't work
I want use kdump & kexec, so I installed kexec-tools, configured /etc/kdump.conf and kdump.service. STFW, according to the steps, I can use kexec -l, then kexec -e, change to the new kernel successfully. But when I use the kexec -p with the same parameter, trigger a panic, the new kernel didn't work without "Starting crashdump kernel...  Bye!"
systemctl is-active kdump
active

/# echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger
[  230.708406] sysrq: Trigger a crash
[  230.711948] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000000
[  230.720290] Mem abort info:
[  230.723110]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  230.729049]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  230.732140]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  230.735304] Data abort info:
[  230.738209]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000044
[  230.742058]   CM = 0, WnR = 1
[  230.745062] user pgtable: 4k pages, 48-bit VAs, pgd = ffff800230cb6000
[  230.751609] [0000000000000000] *pgd=0000000000000000
[  230.756728] Internal error: Oops: 96000044 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[  230.762316] Modules linked in:
[  230.765381] Process bash (pid: 2939, stack limit = 0xffff800230fb4000)
[  230.771926] CPU: 1 PID: 2939 Comm: bash Not tainted 4.14.207-10.3.9.0-2 #1
[  230.778818] Hardware name: Model: Marvell CN9130 development board (CP NOR) setup(A) (DT)
[  230.787015] task: ffff800230c19b80 task.stack: ffff800230fb4000
[  230.792952] pc : sysrq_handle_crash+0x54/0x98
[  230.797319] lr : sysrq_handle_crash+0x40/0x98
[  230.801686] sp : ffff800230fb7d20 pstate : 60000145
[  230.806576] x29: ffff800230fb7d20 x28: ffff800230c19b80 
[  230.811905] x27: ffff000008ee1000 x26: 0000000000000040 
[  230.817234] x25: 0000000000000124 x24: 0000000000000000 
[  230.822562] x23: 000000000000000a x22: ffff000009663990 
[  230.827890] x21: ffff000009616000 x20: 0000000000000063 
[  230.833218] x19: ffff000009616f70 x18: 0000000000005a04 
[  230.838546] x17: 000000000000df54 x16: 0000000000000000 
[  230.843874] x15: 0000000000005a03 x14: 0000000000000038 
[  230.849202] x13: ffff00000970cfa8 x12: 000000000000001c 
[  230.854530] x11: 0000000000000038 x10: 0000000000000990 
[  230.859858] x9 : 0000000000000001 x8 : ffff00000813b000 
[  230.865186] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffff800230c1a4e0 
[  230.870513] x5 : 000000009795e467 x4 : 0000000041e70b64 
[  230.875841] x3 : 940d79af250dbf15 x2 : 0000000000000002 
[  230.881169] x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 0000000000000001 
[  230.886497] Call trace:
[  230.888950]  sysrq_handle_crash+0x54/0x98
[  230.892969]  __handle_sysrq+0xdc/0x248
[  230.896726]  write_sysrq_trigger+0x90/0xa8
[  230.900835]  proc_reg_write+0x6c/0xa0
[  230.904506]  __vfs_write+0x18/0x118
[  230.908003]  vfs_write+0xa8/0x1b8
[  230.911325]  SyS_write+0x50/0xc8
[  230.914563]  __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
[  230.918410] Code: 52800020 b90f8820 d5033e9f d2800001 (39000020) 
[  230.924525] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[  230.928464] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000038
[  230.936573] Mem abort info:
[  230.939373]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  230.945306]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  230.948366]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  230.951513] Data abort info:
[  230.954399]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000004
[  230.958243]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[  230.961218] user pgtable: 4k pages, 48-bit VAs, pgd = ffff800230cb6000
[  230.967760] [0000000000000038] *pgd=0000000000000000
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)

Below information is my configuration, is there any error or a miss? Could somebody help me?
/proc/cmdline
ubi.mtd=6 root=ubi0:rootfs rootwait rootfstype=ubifs console=ttyS1,115200 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xf0512000 mem=8192M rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl proto=tcp ip=192.168.3.196:192.168.3.131:10.4.50.254:255.255.255.0::eth0:on rw crashkernel=1024M debug nokaslr earlyprintk systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1

cat /proc/iomem | grep Crash
  80000000-bfffffff : Crash kernel

cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_size
1073741824

/etc/kdump.conf
# kdump.conf configuration file for kdump service

# Set the NFS server and shared directory path
# nfs 192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl

# Set the path where the crash dump will be stored
path /var/crash

# Specify the URL where the crash dump will be saved
# This can be a local path, an NFS mount, or a remote server
kdump_url file:///var/crash
  
# Configure the core collector tool
#core_collector /sbin/crash
core_collector makedumpfile -c --message-level 1 -d 31

# Reserve memory for kdump as specified in the GRUB configuration
# This should match the 'crashkernel' parameter in your GRUB settings
reserve_memory = 1024M

# Control whether to write the memory contents to the crash dump
write_memory = yes

# Set the timeout for kdump to wait before rebooting the system
timeout = 300

# Enable or disable automatic reboot after a crash dump
reboot = no
default dump_to_rootfs
# Compress the crash dump to save disk space
compress = yes

# Save the crash dump to a remote NFS server
# nfs 192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl

# Configure network settings for the kdump capture kernel
# Replace 'eth0' with the name of your network interface
network eth0
network 192.168.3.196/24

# Configure firewall rules to allow network access for the capture kernel
# This is optional and depends on your network configuration
firewall --rule 22

# Additional options can be added here as needed

/etc/systemd/system/kdump.service
[Unit]
Description=Kernel Crash Dump Service
After=local-fs.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/kexec -p -d /beifen/vmlinux --reuse-cmdline --dtb=/beifen/cn9130-db-A.dtb --command-line="root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl proto=tcp nfsvers=3 rootwait rootfstype=ubifs console=ttyS1,115200 init=/linuxrc earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xf0512000 mem=8192M rw ip=192.168.3.196:192.168.3.131:192.168.3.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:on rw irqpoll nr_cpus=1 reset_devices cgroup_disable=memory mce=off numa=off udev.children-max=2 panic=10 rootflags=nofail acpi_no_memhotplug transparent_hugepage=never nokaslr novmcoredd hest_disable"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded 
1
cat /proc/sys/kernel/kexec_load_disabled
0

When I start kdump, here is the information:
/# systemctl restart kdump
[ 4758.820389] systemd[1]: kdump.service: Deactivated successfully.
[ 4758.821[ 4758.903930] systemd-journald[1835]: Successfully sent stream file descriptor to service manager.
304] systemd[1]: Stopped Kernel Crash Dump Service.
[ 4758.821686] systemd[1]: Stopping Kernel Crash Dump Service...
[ 4758.825076] systemd[1]: Starting Kernel Crash Dump Service...
[ 4758.837512] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _text vaddr = ffff000008080000
[ 4758.837766] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _stext vaddr = ffff000008081000
[ 4758.956751] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol __init_begin vaddr = ffff000009360000
[ 4758.957124] kexec[3082]: arch_process_options:178: command_line: ubi.mtd=6 root=ubi0:rootfs rootwait rootfstype=ubifs console=ttyS1,115200 earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xf0512000 mem=8192M rw root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl proto=tcp ip=192.168.3.196:192.168.3.131:10.4.50.254:255.255.255.0::eth0:on rw debug nokaslr earlyprintk systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1 root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.3.131:/home/zyj/rootfs_mvl proto=tcp nfsvers=3 rootwait rootfstype=ubifs console=ttyS1,115200 init=/linuxrc earlycon=uart8250,mmio32,0xf0512000 mem=8192M rw ip=192.168.3.196:192.168.3.131:192.168.3.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:on rw irqpoll nr_cpus=1 reset_devices cgroup_disable=memory mce=off numa=off udev.children-max=2 panic=10 rootflags=nofail acpi_no_memhotplug transparent_hugepage=never nokaslr novmcoredd hest_disable
[ 4758.957322] kexec[3082]: arch_process_options:180: initrd: (null)
[ 4758.957531] kexec[3082]: arch_process_options:182: dtb: /beifen/cn9130-db-A.dtb
[ 4758.957717] kexec[3082]: arch_process_options:185: console: (null)
[ 4759.240333] kexec[3082]: kernel: 0xffff8a919010 kernel_size: 0x15016d48
[ 4759.240668] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _text vaddr = ffff000008080000
[ 4759.240852] kexec[3082]: Warning, can't get the VA_BITS from kcore
[ 4759.241071] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _stext vaddr = ffff000008081000
[ 4759.241244] kexec[3082]: va_bits : 48
[ 4759.241416] kexec[3082]: page_offset : ffff800000000000
[ 4759.241587] kexec[3082]: set_phys_offset: phys_offset : 0000000000000000 (method : pt_load)
[ 4759.241775] kexec[3082]: get_memory_ranges:+[0] 0000000000000000 - 0000000003ffffff
[ 4759.241947] kexec[3082]: get_memory_ranges:+[1] 0000000004200000 - 00000000043fffff
[ 4759.242120] kexec[3082]: get_memory_ranges:+[2] 0000000005400000 - 00000000bfffffff
[ 4759.242398] kexec[3082]: get_memory_ranges:+[3] 0000000100000000 - 000000023fffffff
[ 4759.242572] kexec[3082]: System RAM ranges;
[ 4759.242742] kexec[3082]: 0000000000000000-0000000003ffffff (0)
[ 4759.242909] kexec[3082]: 0000000004200000-00000000043fffff (0)
[ 4759.243090] kexec[3082]: 0000000005400000-00000000bfffffff (0)
[ 4759.243258] kexec[3082]: 0000000100000000-000000023fffffff (0)
[ 4759.243423] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: e_entry:        ffff000008080000
[ 4759.243718] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: p_vaddr:        ffff000008080000
[ 4759.243892] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: header_offset:  0000000000000000
[ 4759.244157] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: kernel_segment: 0000000080000000
[ 4759.244341] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: text_offset:    0000000000080000
[ 4759.244526] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: image_size:     0000000003f65000
[ 4759.244696] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: phys_offset:    0000000000000000
[ 4759.244865] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: vp_offset:      ffff000008000000
[ 4759.245033] kexec[3082]: elf_arm64_load: PE format:      yes
[ 4759.245202] kexec[3082]: Reserved memory range
[ 4759.245371] kexec[3082]: 0000000080000000-00000000bfffffff (0)
[ 4759.245539] kexec[3082]: Coredump memory ranges
[ 4759.245708] kexec[3082]: 0000000000000000-0000000003ffffff (0)
[ 4759.245888] kexec[3082]: 0000000004200000-00000000043fffff (0)
[ 4759.246058] kexec[3082]: 0000000005400000-000000007fffffff (0)
[ 4759.246228] kexec[3082]: 0000000100000000-000000023fffffff (0)
[ 4759.246398] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _text vaddr = ffff000008080000
[ 4759.246568] kexec[3082]: kernel symbol _text vaddr = ffff000008080000
[ 4759.246748] kexec[3082]: va_bits : 48
[ 4759.246918] kexec[3082]: page_offset : ffff800000000000
[ 4759.247087] kexec[3082]: load_crashdump_segments: page_offset:   ffff800000000000
[ 4759.247269] kexec[3082]: get_crash_notes_per_cpu: crash_notes addr = 23746a200, size = 424
[ 4759.247440] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 4, p_offset = 0x23746a200 p_paddr = 0x23746a200 p_vaddr = 0x0 p_filesz = 0x1a8 p_memsz = 0x1a8
[ 4759.247724] kexec[3082]: get_crash_notes_per_cpu: crash_notes addr = 237645200, size = 424
[ 4759.247903] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 4, p_offset = 0x237645200 p_paddr = 0x237645200 p_vaddr = 0x0 p_filesz = 0x1a8 p_memsz = 0x1a8
[ 4759.248110] kexec[3082]: get_crash_notes_per_cpu: crash_notes addr = 237820200, size = 424
[ 4759.248283] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 4, p_offset = 0x237820200 p_paddr = 0x237820200 p_vaddr = 0x0 p_filesz = 0x1a8 p_memsz = 0x1a8
[ 4759.248450] kexec[3082]: get_crash_notes_per_cpu: crash_notes addr = 2379fb200, size = 424
[ 4759.248616] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 4, p_offset = 0x2379fb200 p_paddr = 0x2379fb200 p_vaddr = 0x0 p_filesz = 0x1a8 p_memsz = 0x1a8
[ 4759.248796] kexec[3082]: vmcoreinfo header: p_type = 4, p_offset = 0x235008000 p_paddr = 0x235008000 p_vaddr = 0x0 p_filesz = 0x1024 p_memsz = 0x1024
[ 4759.248962] kexec[3082]: Kernel text Elf header: p_type = 1, p_offset = 0x7080000 p_paddr = 0x7080000 p_vaddr = 0xffff000008080000 p_filesz = 0x2354000 p_memsz = 0x2354000
[ 4759.249129] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 1, [ 4759.662167] systemd-journald[1835]: /var/log/journal/6f090d1f237546fda94534ae49608464/system.journal: Allocation limit reached, rotating.
p_offset = 0x0 p[ 4759.675967] systemd-journald[1835]: Journal file /var/log/journal/6f090d1f237546fda94534ae49608464/system.journal is full, rotating to a new file
_paddr = 0x0 p_v[ 4759.690480] systemd-journald[1835]: Rotating...
addr = 0xffff800[ 4759.697049] systemd-journald[1835]: Reserving 333 entries in field hash table.
000000000 p_file[ 4759.706077] systemd-journald[1835]: Reserving 2047 entries in data hash table.
sz = 0x4000000 p[ 4759.714117] systemd-journald[1835]: Vacuuming...
_memsz = 0x4000000
[ 4759.24929[ 4759.721974] systemd-journald[1835]: Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal/6f090d1f237546fda94534ae49608464.
4] kexec[3082]: [ 4759.725699] systemd-journald[1835]: Failed to re-enable copy-on-write for /var/log/journal/6f090d1f237546fda94534ae49608464/system@43c4b96683db4bd4840786b8d83dea55-0000000000002aac-000622d9fbee7478.journal: Inappropriate ioctl for device, rewriting file
Elf header: p_type = 1, p_offset = 0x4200000 p_paddr = 0x4200000 p_vaddr = 0xffff800004200000 p_filesz = 0x200000 p_memsz = 0x200000
[ 4759.583064] kexec[3082][ 4759.771594] systemd-journald[1835]: Failed to re-enable copy-on-write for /var/log/journal/6f090d1f237546fda94534ae49608464/system@43c4b96683db4bd4840786b8d83dea55-0000000000002aac-000622d9fbee7478.journal: Inappropriate ioctl for device, rewriting file
: Elf header: p_type = 1, p_offs[ 4759.797715] systemd-journald[1835]: Retrying write.
et = 0x5400000 p_paddr = 0x5400000 p_vaddr = 0xffff800005400000 p_filesz = 0x7ac00000 p_memsz = 0x7ac00000
[ 4759.583257] kexec[3082]: Elf header: p_type = 1, p_offset = 0x100000000 p_paddr = 0x100000000 p_vaddr = 0xffff800100000000 p_filesz = 0x140000000 p_memsz = 0x140000000
[ 4759.583426] kexec[3082]: load_crashdump_segments: elfcorehdr 0xbffff000-0xbffff3ff
[ 4759.583594] kexec[3082]: arm64_load_other_segments:741: purgatory sink: 0x0
[ 4759.583760] kexec[3082]: get_cells_size: #address-cells:2 #size-cells:2
[ 4759.583925] kexec[3082]: cells_size_fitted: bffff000-bffff3ff
[ 4759.584169] kexec[3082]: cells_size_fitted: 80000000-bfffffff
[ 4759.725213] kexec[3082]: setup_2nd_dtb: no kaslr-seed found
[ 4759.725786] kexec[3082]: dtb_delete_property: fdt_delprop failed: <valid offset/length>
[ 4759.725980] kexec[3082]: dtb_delete_property: fdt_delprop failed: <valid offset/length>
[ 4759.726164] kexec[3082]: dtb:    base 83fe5000, size 83a5h (33701)
[ 4759.726348] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_starts info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: f80 size: 50
[ 4759.726553] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_starts value: 83feef80 addr: 83fee014
[ 4759.726739] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 9000000094000000->90000000940003db
[ 4759.726923] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.728539] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee0f8 addr: 83fee018
[ 4759.728741] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 f940001390000000->f940001390000000
[ 4759.728928] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.729116] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee0f8 addr: 83fee01c
[ 4759.729320] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC aa1303f5f9400013->aa1303f5f9407c13
[ 4759.729514] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_update info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 2ef0 size: c
[ 4759.729697] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_update value: 83ff0ef0 addr: 83fee034
[ 4759.729879] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 eb14027f94000000->eb14027f94000baf
[ 4759.730061] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_finish info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 2f00 size: 194
[ 4759.730247] kexec[3082]: sym: sha256_finish value: 83ff0f00 addr: 83fee04c
[ 4759.730428] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 d280040294000000->d280040294000bad
[ 4759.730613] kexec[3082]: sym:     memcmp info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 66c size: 34
[ 4759.730806] kexec[3082]: sym: memcmp value: 83fee66c addr: 83fee05c
[ 4759.730988] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 3400042094000000->3400042094000184
[ 4759.731173] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.731354] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee100 addr: 83fee064
[ 4759.731537] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 9000001490000000->9000001490000000
[ 4759.731722] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.731904] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee110 addr: 83fee068
[ 4759.732086] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 9100029490000014->9100029490000014
[ 4759.732287] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.732471] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee110 addr: 83fee06c
[ 4759.732653] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADD_ABS_LO12_NC f940000091000294->f940000091044294
[ 4759.732835] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.733018] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee100 addr: 83fee070
[ 4759.733199] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC d2800013f9400000->d2800013f9408000
[ 4759.733381] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4759.733563] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee078
[ 4759.733744] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 9000000094000000->9000000094000147
[ 4759.733925] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4759.734108] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee108 addr: 83fee07c
[ 4759.734306] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 f940000090000000->f940000090000000
[ 4759.734498] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.068430] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee108 addr: 83fee080
[ 4760.069702] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 94000000f9400000->94000000f9408400
[ 4760.069921] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.070135] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee084
[ 4760.070352] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 f940028094000000->f940028094000144
[ 4760.070558] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.070765] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee094
[ 4760.070972] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 f100827f94000000->f100827f94000140
[ 4760.071178] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.071383] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee118 addr: 83fee0a0
[ 4760.071588] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 d280001390000016->d280001390000016
[ 4760.071809] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.072048] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee118 addr: 83fee0a8
[ 4760.072248] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 910402b5f94002c0->910402b5f9408ec0
[ 4760.072438] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.072640] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee0b0
[ 4760.072832] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 9000000094000000->9000000094000139
[ 4760.073026] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.073222] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee120 addr: 83fee0b4
[ 4760.073415] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 f940000090000000->f940000090000000
[ 4760.073608] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.073800] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee120 addr: 83fee0b8
[ 4760.073989] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 94000000f9400000->94000000f9409000
[ 4760.074182] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.074372] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee0bc
[ 4760.074563] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 f940028094000000->f940028094000136
[ 4760.074756] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.074947] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee0cc
[ 4760.075142] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 f100827f94000000->f100827f94000132
[ 4760.075340] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.075533] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee118 addr: 83fee0d8
[ 4760.075724] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 94000000f94002c0->94000000f9408ec0
[ 4760.075919] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.076111] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee0dc
[ 4760.076304] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 5280002094000000->528000209400012e
[ 4760.076770] kexec[3082]: sym:      .data info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 6 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.076976] kexec[3082]: sym: .data value: 83ff13f8 addr: 83fee0f8
[ 4760.077169] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff13f8
[ 4760.077365] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.077560] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10a0 addr: 83fee100
[ 4760.077766] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10a0
[ 4760.077961] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.078152] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10c0 addr: 83fee108
[ 4760.078345] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10c0
[ 4760.078537] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.411800] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10d0 addr: 83fee110
[ 4760.411995] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10d0
[ 4760.412220] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.412404] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10d6 addr: 83fee118
[ 4760.412588] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10d6
[ 4760.412770] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.412951] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10d8 addr: 83fee120
[ 4760.413133] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10d8
[ 4760.413315] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.413499] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee168 addr: 83fee128
[ 4760.413681] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 a9bf7bfd90000000->a9bf7bfd90000000
[ 4760.413876] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.414059] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee168 addr: 83fee134
[ 4760.414241] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 94000000f9400000->94000000f940b400
[ 4760.414429] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4760.414612] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83fee138
[ 4760.414795] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 9400000094000000->9400000094000117
[ 4760.414978] kexec[3082]: sym: setup_arch info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: f20 size: 3c
[ 4760.415173] kexec[3082]: sym: setup_arch value: 83feef20 addr: 83fee13c
[ 4760.415367] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 9000000094000000->9000000094000379
[ 4760.415550] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.415733] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee170 addr: 83fee140
[ 4760.415915] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 f940000090000000->f940000090000000
[ 4760.416096] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.416277] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83fee170 addr: 83fee144
[ 4760.416826] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC b9412000f9400000->b9412000f940b800
[ 4760.417028] kexec[3082]: sym: verify_sha256_digest info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: f4
[ 4760.417221] kexec[3082]: sym: verify_sha256_digest value: 83fee000 addr: 83fee150
[ 4760.417407] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 3400004094000000->3400004097ffffac
[ 4760.417592] kexec[3082]: sym: post_verification_setup_arch info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: f08 size: c
[ 4760.417777] kexec[3082]: sym: post_verification_setup_arch value: 83feef08 addr: 83fee160
[ 4760.417989] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: JUMP26 d503201f14000000->d503201f1400036a
[ 4760.418175] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.418357] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 value: 83ff10e8 addr: 83fee168
[ 4760.418541] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff10e8
[ 4760.418723] kexec[3082]: sym:      .data info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 6 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4760.418904] kexec[3082]: sym: .data value: 83ff13f8 addr: 83fee170
[ 4761.103979] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC 14000000f9400000->14000000f947bc00
[ 4761.104162] kexec[3082]: sym:     printf info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 594 size: 78
[ 4761.104344] kexec[3082]: sym: printf value: 83fee594 addr: 83feef58
[ 4761.104525] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: JUMP26 d503201f14000000->d503201f17fffd8f
[ 4761.104708] kexec[3082]: sym: arm64_kernel_entry info: 10 other: 00 shndx: 6 value: 128 size: 8
[ 4761.104890] kexec[3082]: sym: arm64_kernel_entry value: 83ff1520 addr: 83feef60
[ 4761.105072] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: ABS64 0000000000000000->0000000083ff1520
[ 4761.105255] kexec[3082]: sym: .rodata.str1.1 info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 3 value: 0 size: 0
**[ 4761.105482] systemd[1]: Finished Kernel Crash Dump Service.**
[ 4761.442732] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: CALL26 f100fedf94000000->f100fedf97fff848
[ 4761.442919] kexec[3082]: sym:     memcpy info: 12 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 64c size: 20
[ 4761.443108] kexec[3082]: sym: memcpy value: 83fee64c addr: 83ff0ee4
[ 4761.443291] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: JUMP26 d503201f14000000->d503201f17fff5da
[ 4761.443483] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4761.443680] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83ff1098 addr: 83ff0f08
[ 4761.787901] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: PREL32 0000010800000000->00000108fffffa5c
[ 4761.788116] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4761.788308] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83ff0ef0 addr: 83ff13c4
[ 4761.788494] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: PREL32 0000000c00000000->0000000cfffffb2c
[ 4761.788682] kexec[3082]: sym:      .text info: 03 other: 00 shndx: 1 value: 0 size: 0
[ 4761.788868] kexec[3082]: sym: .text value: 83ff0f00 addr: 83ff13d8
[ 4761.789069] kexec[3082]: machine_apply_elf_rel: PREL32 0000019400000000->00000194fffffb28
[ 4761.789258] kexec[3082]: **kexec_load: entry = 0x83fee6a0 flags = 0xb70001**
[ 4761.789444] kexec[3082]: nr_segments = 5
[ 4761.789629] kexec[3082]: segment[0].buf   = 0xffff8a929010
[ 4761.789815] kexec[3082]: segment[0].bufsz = 0x1a4bc50
[ 4761.790000] kexec[3082]: segment[0].mem   = 0x80080000
[ 4761.790185] kexec[3082]: segment[0].memsz = 0x1a4c000
[ 4761.790382] kexec[3082]: segment[1].buf   = 0xffff8c379010
[ 4761.790569] kexec[3082]: segment[1].bufsz = 0x1836a00
[ 4761.790764] kexec[3082]: segment[1].mem   = 0x81ad0000
[ 4761.790952] kexec[3082]: segment[1].memsz = 0x250f000
[ 4761.791137] kexec[3082]: segment[2].buf   = 0xaaaaef28b3d0
[ 4761.791323] kexec[3082]: segment[2].bufsz = 0x83a5
[ 4761.791507] kexec[3082]: segment[2].mem   = 0x83fe5000
[ 4761.791705] kexec[3082]: segment[2].memsz = 0x9000
[ 4761.791892] kexec[3082]: segment[3].buf   = 0xaaaaef293ce0
[ 4761.792128] kexec[3082]: segment[3].bufsz = 0x3578
[ 4761.792319] kexec[3082]: segment[3].mem   = 0x83fee000
[ 4761.792508] kexec[3082]: segment[3].memsz = 0x4000
[ 4761.792695] kexec[3082]: segment[4].buf   = 0xaaaaef278480
[ 4761.792881] kexec[3082]: segment[4].bufsz = 0x400
[ 4761.793067] kexec[3082]: segment[4].mem   = 0xbffff000
[ 4761.793268] kexec[3082]: segment[4].memsz = 0x1000


So the "panic" you showed above is not the failure (or success) of the crashkernel starting - it is all still the output of your ordinary host kernel (it's "reaction" to the SysRq-C).
Your kernel messages show a 2nd pagefault (the Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000038 - notice 0x38 not 0 as in the "triggered" one), not sure where, code-wise, this sits, and it's conceivable this happens during the attempt to "handover" to the crashkernel. But at least the log / console messages you show do not have evidence of the crashkernel loading or booting. Without access to your specific hardware, it's hard to "hint" what could be behind this. I'd troubleshoot somewhere along those lines:

any other console messages following these ? Or is the console / system stuck at this point ?
when "there", does the system still react to SysRq ? If so, it's an indication the crashkernel hasn't booted; use SysRq (t,l,w, ...) to extract more diags on what the system might (not) be doing then.
does it still react to NMI (many systems allow NMI to be triggered either by button or by mgmt controller; again, I do not know what kind of ARM system - developer baseboard, server machine, anything-in-between) you have. If so, what is shown ?
you could try passing more-verbose/more-"chatty" command line options, and/or additional debug-only console devices, to the crashkernel using kexec -p --append=... and see if that gives any more output.
likewise, make your host kernel's console output as verbose (echo 9 > /proc/sysrq-trigger) as possible before triggering the panic.

Also, try getting help through the kexec mailing list, http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/kexec/ - it's reasonably active.

Actually, the message above is all I can collect, the console / system stuck at the point, watchdog would be triggered after 60s, I couldn't input any commands.
The CPU architecture is ARMv8, don't support NMI.
"kexec -p --append=...verbosity=7 earlyprintk ignore_loglevel systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1", but still no more output.
The problem occured after triggering panic and before starting the new kernel, we don't know what happend in between. I'm not sure if it's a kexec parameter configuration issue or some other problem.
